# Java jconsole application by name

Tags: java, tomcat, jconsole

I frequently use jconsole to connect to local tomcat. Is possible connect not by PID, but process name? Because for day I have to restart tomcat many times and each time I need to connect with jconsole to invoke some operation on mbean - if it possible to use process name or some part of it - e.g. *catalina* - it will save many time.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Java are you using? In `jdk 1.6.0_25` that I have installed, `jconsole` responds with both name and PID for local running processes when prompted for *New Connection*.

A side note, if you like `jconsole` then you'll love `jvisualvm` which became part of the jdk at some early update of version 6. On top of that, `jconsole` can run as a plugin from within `jvisualvm`.